# Adding language file in joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I've mentioned my component name in menu in `sys.ini` file.  I've mentioned this on xml file also, but the language file didnt change in Joomla 1.5

language/en-GB/en-GB.com_examsmsstaff.sys.ini

```
COM_EXAM="Exam"
```

Xml file

```
<languages folder="admin">
    <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB/en-GB.com_examsmsstaff.sys.ini</language>
</languages>
```

Answer (score 0):

Joomla is pretty fussy about naming conventions.  take the .sys. out of the file name and you should see it working (assuming that your component is installed and working as com_examsmsstaff)

Answer (score 0):

`.sys.ini` files [only work in Joomla 1.6 and above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146890/joomla-v1-5-plugin-sys-ini-language-file).  If you're looking to name menu items, place the code into a file named `.menu.ini`.

For instance, your file above would be:

```
en-GB.com_examsmsstaff.menu.ini
```