# Joomla v1.5 plugin sys.ini language file

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

Is it possible to use sys.ini language file for Joomla v1.5 plugin? I want to use it during plugin install. Because default language ini file is not accessible during installation process. So install manager outputs only language key constants like PLG_MY_PLUGIN_DESCRIPTION. I haven't found any hint about it in Joomla v1.5 developer manuals. So I guess sys.ini files work only with components?

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Joomla 1.5 does not read .sys.ini language files. Only Joomla 1.6 and above do.
If you turn on the debug tool (Site>>Global Congiguration>>System) then it will show you if the language file is being loaded.

A few other things to check:

1. The description in the XML matches the one in the language file.
2. Each line at the beginning of the language file for the description area starts with a hash tag `#` rather than `;`
3. The XML points to the language file in the correct location.

If you have checked all of these then please post some code for the `.XML` and `.INI` files.

Regards

Comment: plugin XML file - http://pastebin.com/rc4jukpi, language ini file: http://pastebin.com/mTjaEJ5A. So after installing it I get message - Install Plugin Success and plugin description- PLUGIN DESC. But instead of this I want to get text - "This is Joomla v1.5 content plugin."

Comment: Also found some good information about plugin language files in Joomla v1.5 - http://www.packtpub.com/article/customizing-plugins-in-joomla-1.5x-part1

Comment: Depending this topic found a discussion in Joomla forum: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=476&t=308668

Comment: try changing `PLUGIN DESC` to `PLUGIN_DESC`

Comment: and according to you XML file, the language file is in the root folder yeah?