# Component's page showing CONSTANT_KEYS rather than showing their equivalents from en-GB.com_comname.ini file

Tags: key, components, joomla3.3

I am currently developing my very first **Joomla 3.x Component** just for the learning purpose. Everything is happening as I am expecting except one problem.

> A few titles and labels on component's page are **showing constant keys rather than showing their equivalents** from `en-GB.com_somthing.ini` file**.

Just like, its showing in <h1>...</h1> tags `COM_SOMETHING_MANAGER_SOMETHINGS` rather than **Somthings Manager**.

Though the question [Joomla v1.5 plugin sys.ini language file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146890/joomla-v1-5-plugin-sys-ini-language-file) is not relevant to that of mine still I followed it, but no result.

Please can anyone suggest me troubleshooting ways in detail, like what things should I check and in what order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still nobody, I think, even have seen to my question, but thank god, **I found the solution myself**. I am sharing the details for someone else who is also new to Joomla Development and trying to follow some tutorial or manual.

The tutorial I am following told me to place language files in path just like

`localhost/joomla-site/administrator/components/com_comname/language/en-GB/`

now these files were actually ignored by Joomla as it found the files in

```
localhost/joomla-site/administrator/language/en-GB/
```

and the content written just in these files were working.

---

**Solution**
I simply deleted files `en-GB.com_comname.ini` and `en-GB.com_comname.sys.ini` from

```
localhost/joomla-site/administrator/language/en-GB/
```

so now Joomla is reading these files only from

`localhost/joomla-site/administrator/components/com_comname/language/en-GB/`

and all titles and labels are just perfect now.